# Unique items in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

What's the recommended way to ensure all the items of an ArrayList list are unique either by extending the ArrayList or using another container?

```
class ProList extends ArrayList
{
    public <E> boolean super_add(E e)
    {
        if(this.contains(e)) {
            System.out.println("Item not added because it exists already.");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return this.add(e);
    }
};
```

The above works but it's full of warnings and sees a bit hacky...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to maintain insertion order and uniqueness (as defined by hashCode() and equals(), which you will need to properly override and implement in any classes going into the colelction), use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Comment: Is there any chance the order of the items I enter using ArrayList to not be ordered the way I put them?

Comment: No, elements in an `ArrayList` maintain the order they were inserted in.

Comment: Is the order maintained with a simple HashSet?

Comment: No, `HashSets` do not guarantee any particular order; in fact, the order in which you iterate over things might even change as you add elements.

Comment: @Luka no, `HashSet` doesn't maintain any *consistent* order at all. For your specific requirement, seems that you want/need to use `LinkedHashSet`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't *have* to use an `ArrayList`, I'd recommend checking out Java's [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interfaces. A regular [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) would likely offer you the best performance. [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) would work if you want elements to maintain logical order. [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) would work if you want to maintain insertion order, as if it were an `ArrayList`. You'll have to override `equals()` to use any set, and to use the hash-based sets, you'll need to also override `hashCode()`.